# Как вызвать метод в dll из юнити скрипт?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть очень простой dll с именем `MyNativeDll`, который содержит вот такой метод

```
extern "C" {
    int foo() { return 777; }
}
```

Я делаю билд для этого `MyNativeDll.dll` и складываю его в Assert директорию.

Теперь мне нунжно обратиться к этому методу из моего юнити проекта. Я создаю скрипт:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string pluginName = "MyNativeDll";
    //native interface
    [DllImport(pluginName)]
    private static extern int foo();

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int i = foo();
        Debug.Log($"HERE :: {i}");
    }
}
```

Если я запускаю этот проект то в консоле выпадает вот такая ошибка

```
EntryPointNotFoundException: foo
TestScript.Update () (at Assets/TestScript.cs:20)
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Я не спец в c#, но вроде как в ``DllImport`` нужно указывать полное имя файла ``MyNativeDll.dll``, а не ``MyNativeDll``

Comment: @Александр нет, указывается только имя dll